# Actionscript 3.0 Keyboard event listener doesn't implement the function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, keylistener, event-listener

I have this keyboard event listener to listen for key_Down of letter A and D but I end up with and error:

**1119: Access of possibly undefined property A through a reference with static type Class.**

**When I use**

```
function rotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode==68) {
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 90 }
}

function unrotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode==65) {
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 0 }
}
```

**instead of (keyBoard.A and keyboard.D, I no longer get and error but the function that rotates the images doesn't work. Is it that it can't recognize the current target and implement the function or something else?**

```
ti.border = true
ti.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onInput);

function onInput(event:TextEvent):void {
  if(ti.text.search('a')!=-1) load_image("http://i54.tinypic.com/anom5d.png", "ottefct");
  else if(ti.text.search('b')!=-1) load_image("http://i53.tinypic.com/2dv7dao.png", "rnd");
  else if(ti.text.search('c')!=-1) load_image("http://i51.tinypic.com/m8jp7m.png", "ssd");
}

var loaded_images:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function load_image(url:String, id_name:String)
{
  var loader:Loader = new Loader();
  loader.name = id_name;
  var url_req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadingComplete);
  loader.load(url_req);
}

function onLoadingComplete(evt:Event):void
{
  var img_name:String = evt.currentTarget.loader.name
  var spr_box:Sprite = new Sprite();
  spr_box.addChild(evt.currentTarget.loader);

  spr_box.mouseChildren = false;
  spr_box.doubleClickEnabled = true;

  spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
  spr_box.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
  spr_box.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rotate);
  spr_box.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, unrotate);

  spr_box.width = 124;
  spr_box.height = 180;
  spr_box.x = 430;
  spr_box.y = 425;


  this.addChild(spr_box);
  loaded_images[img_name] = spr_box;
}


function drag(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
  evt.currentTarget.startDrag()
}

function drop(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
  evt.currentTarget.stopDrag()
}

function rotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if (evt.keyCode==Keyboard.D) {
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 90 
  }
}

function unrotate(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
  if (evt.keyCode==Keyboard.A) {
    evt.currentTarget.rotation = 0 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach the `KeyBoardEvent` to the stage not an object

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rotate);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, unrotate);
```

Comment: I tried this but I ended up with another error.                  **Error: Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.display::Stage/set rotation()
 at project_fla::MainTimeline/unrotate()**

Comment: if you have an uppercase "S" make it lower case and also try it without anything so just `addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rotate);`

Comment: That didn't work, as well. Without **stage** I don't get an error anymore but the function still isn't being implemented.

Comment: That's the problem, I think, because in one of the rotate functions, I put a trace code that would display in the output box, "A key is pressed" and the function wouldn't even trace that so I don't know if the eventListeners are picking up the keyDowns or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

or even better using [Fingers](http://filimanjaro.com/fingers)

```
on(stage).keyDown += rotate + unrotate;
```

Have in mind, that you have to change `evt.currentTarget` in your listeners, so it points to an instance of `DisplayObject` you want to rotate.

What's more, it would be clearer to have one `stage_keyDownHandler` instead of `rotate` and `unrotate`:

```
 stage_keyDownHandler(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
 {
      if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
          yourObjToRotate.rotation = 90 
      }
      else if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
          yourObjToRotate.rotation = 0 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the object, it select its current Target. But when you press key code, how can it selects its target? You must define its instance name when you press a key code.